# Git pull the chanes from another branch into current branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I have four branches:

1. Master,
2. Branch 1
3. Branch 2
4. Branch 3

Dev 1 is working into Branch 1, Dev 2 is working in Branch 2, and Dev 3 is working in Branch 3.

Now I need to pull the changes of Branch 1 into Branch 3, **not merge**. So that in future Dev 1 continue to work on Branch 1 and Dev 3 has all codes from Dev 1 as well as Branch 3.

How can we do this?

Comment: This is what the definition of `merge`

Answer (score 1):

You can take pull of Branch 1 in Branch 3 then all changes form Branch 1 will be in Branch 3

```
git checkout Branch 3
git pull origin Branch 1
```

Comment: This will do a merge

Comment: I think in that case you have to cherry-pick the only commits of Branch 1 which you need in Branch 3.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably a bad thing to do. I would personally *merge* in from the branch I want changes from. From my understanding you’re looking for [**cherry-pick**](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/cherry-pick):

`git cherry-pick commit`

Answer (score 0):

> Now I need to pull the changes of Branch 1 into Branch 3, not merge. So that in future Dev 1 continue to work on Branch 1 and Dev 3 has all codes from Dev 1 as well as Branch 3

You can't. Changes in one branch do not magically percolate live into another branch.

You *can* make it so that branch 3 acquires all the "changes" that are in branch 1 *now*. That is what a merge is, or a rebase. But you can *not* make it so that *future* changes in branch 1 somehow pass thru a wormhole and simply appear in branch 3 on dev 3's machine. The only way to make that happen is for dev 3 to acquire the "changes" from branch 1 *again*.

And that is not an unreasonable thing to do. When I'm working on a feature, I pull `develop` and rebase my branch onto it, every hour or so. So that way, I always have the latest "changes" from `develop`. But not because of magic. Because of *me*.